# Add a special character o glyph made of three dots for quick insertion InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, icon, typesetting, formatting

I am working on a long text with InDesign cs6 and I need to be able to quickly write/insert a special charter that looks likes this three dots in the image  [image: ...] 
(They are three dots and the middle on is higher making them look like a triangle.)
any ideas are more than welcome!
Thank you!

Comment: There are so many possible ways that in order to give the best advice, you should be more specific about your workflow and your layout

Answer (score 2):

You may already have a font with that symbol. It is a Math Symbol. Here is a link to how to find it.
https://indesignsecrets.com/find-font-glyph.php
Hope this helps!

Comment: That's right. It's the "therefore" symbol. Unicode 2234. Here's a list of (some) fonts that includes it: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2234/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, but I see two options:

1. Find a font which has this glyph (very unlikely, because this is not a typical unicode character).
2. Type '???' or 'XYZ' or something very distinct in the normal text flow every time you need to have the symbol added. When you're done writing and adding the 'XYZ' everywhere, draw this symbol as an icon, copy to clipboard and run a Search & replace, switching 'XYZ' for Clipboard contents.

[image]